# Footer to the bottom of the screen without having a 100vh set material ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am building react app with MUI framework and I have tried many different solutions to get a sticky footer to the bottom of my screen but none of them satisfied what I wanted. The one I am the most satisfied is the following:

```
export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        width:'100%',
        overflow:'hidden',
        bottom:'0',
        left:'0',
      }}
    >
      <CssBaseline />
      <Box
        component="footer"
        sx={{
          py: 3,
          px: 2,
          mt: 'auto',
          backgroundColor: (theme) =>
            theme.palette.mode === 'light'
              ? theme.palette.grey[200]
              : theme.palette.grey[800],
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <Typography variant="body1">
            Add stuff here
          </Typography>
          <Copyright />
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The problem with this is that if there is not enough content on the page then the footer will be at the middle of the page. One work around was to add to the footer component `min-height:100vh` but it is a problem because it leaves a big blank above the footer when there is enough content this time.
Is there a way to do this so it does not get stuck in the middle neither I have a big white space if it's at the bottom?
I call my footer in my app.js component

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
        <Route path="/private" element={<Private />}>
          <Route path="/private/private-home" element={<PrivateHome />} />
          <Route path="/private/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how I accomplish this in raw HTML/CSS. Note the body should have margin:0; on it so you don't get double scroll bars, but it'll keep the footer at the bottom of the page & make the content section scroll independently.

Hope it helps!

```
<div style="display:flex; height:100vh; overflow:hidden; flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="flex-grow:1; overflow:auto; background-color:red;">
        Body Content
    </div>
    <div style="min-height: 90px; height: 90px; background-color:green;">
        Footer content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, yes this works but not as I want because if my body content dooes not have enough content it will just leave a big blank in the page until the footer is here.